# is angular's promises misleading in that they are not always called asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I've recently have been debugging some stuff related to promises in angular.js and noticed that angular puts resolutions of promises into its evalAsync loop as depicted in [this diagram](http://blog.xebia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/evan-async-loop.png). I was under impression that promise callbacks are always executed in asynchronously (as a new event in a event queue). However, with angular's mechanism it's possible that if any of the promises is resolved during digest cycle and angular starts another iteration on digest the callback for the promise will be called in the same execution stack since `evalAsync` queue is always checked first:

```
do { // "while dirty" loop
  dirty = false;
  current = target;

  while (asyncQueue.length) {
    try {
      asyncTask = asyncQueue.shift();
      asyncTask.scope.$eval(asyncTask.expression, asyncTask.locals);
    } catch (e) {
      $exceptionHandler(e);
    }
    lastDirtyWatch = null;
  }

  traverseScopesLoop:
  do { // "traverse the scopes" loop
  ...
  } while ((current = next));
...  
} while (dirty || asyncQueue.length);
```

Is is not misleading?

Comment: That's the way promises are supposed to work. A function can't really tell if it's in one particular event loop or another anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I was under impression that promises are always resolved in a new event loop since resolving in the same event loop isn't really asynchronous, right?

Comment: That's true, but because your callback doesn't *know* what will happen, it has to be written as if it were called asynchronously.

Comment: Actually after doing some reading I think my comments are wrong; the promise spec is more subtle and robust than I had thought, and I don't know enough about what's going on in Angular to judge it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether I'd call that misleading or not. Fact is:

- Promise callbacks are always executed asynchronously. They are never called before the `.then()` they were passed to returns.
  To a greater extent, they are even never called from user code - there is "only platform code" on the stack as mandated by the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/).
- It is not guaranteed that every asynchronous callback executes on its own event loop turn. There is no requirement that two callbacks must not share the same event loop cycle. After all, they cannot distinguish that anyway.

In your case, Angular qualifies as platform code, which uses its own "event loop" - the digest cycle.

Comment: So if I pass a function to a `.then()` method on an already-fulfilled promise instance, the implementation has to do something like schedule an immediate timeout to invoke it? Or wait until some interval timer finds it? That's weird, but the spec certainly does read that way.

Comment: @Pointy: Exactly that. The spec guarantees asynchrony. No weird corner cases where your callback sometimes happens before `.then(…)` returns, only because a promise is unexpectedly already fulfilled.

Comment: OK, right. The `setImmediate()` gecko bug discussion is rambling but informative. This issue seems to be an interesting and deceptively complicated one, beyond the basic behavioral guarantees (which aren't complicated).

Comment: @Bergi, thanks, so as I understand the takeaway here is that _callbacks are never called before the .then() they were passed to returns_, however, the callback _can_ be executed in the same event loop as a function calling `.then()` method by some _platform code_ when _user code_ stack exists, correct?

Comment: @Maximus: Yes, it can be executed in the same event loop turn as the call to `then`, but not when still some user code is on the stack. A (contrived) example would be `p.then(function(){ p.then(/*… later */); …} /* can be *now* */)` - the inner callback can be invoked right after the outer one returned.

Comment: @Bergi, I see, thanks. I didn't understand your example though. Can you please post it as part of your answer in a readable formatting. I've formatted it and it seems that you've put `/* can be *now* */` part in the wrong place or I'm missing something.

Comment: @Maximus: No, I deliberately put it after the first function. But it probably was a bad idea to put this into code. What I meant was that in the situation `promise.then(function a(){ … promise.then(b); … })` both callbacks can be executed in the same turn of the event loop: `a(); b();` even if `b` was registered on the promise within `a()`. But from the scope of the `a` function it does not make any difference, `b` is always executed "later", after the user code "`…`".

Comment: @Bergi, you say that "both callbacks *can* be executed in the same turn of the event loop".Do you mean that under some circumstance, they will not?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: I meant that this is implementation-dependent. An implementation can choose to defer such calls to the next turn, or to execute them as soon as possible. Angular seems to do he latter.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you for the explanation. "can" makes total sense now.